# Recycler view scrolls but does not scroll to the end

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am designing a shopping app via Kotlin & Firebase. I am using recycler view in an inbuilt fragment . There is one activity which is responsible for multiple fragments , for example one fragment is responsible for displaying orders , one fragment is responsible displaying all products etc. I get all my data from firebase & display it in fragments via a recycler view. The issue is that the recycler view scrolls but it does not scroll to the end of the page. Can someone guide me. I have attached two screenshots

(Recycler view does not scroll to the end of the last child i.e "TAP TO KNOW MORE" textview is not visible for the last element of recycler view, it just stops scrolling)

[image]

[image]

This is how my activity is designed ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bgColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how my fragment is designed ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_dashboard_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_dashboard_item_found"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/no_dashboard_item_found"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how my recycler view item is designed ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="265dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_item_image_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                />

            <com.example.shopperista.utils.CustomTextViewStyleBold
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_name_dashboard"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/guitar"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                />

            <com.example.shopperista.utils.CustomTextViewStyle
                android:id="@+id/tv_item_price_dashboard"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/rs_2500"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tap_to_know_more"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the XML for `<fragment>` as follows:

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>
```

The main part is changing the `android:layout_height` from `match_parent` to `0dp` as you want the fragment to take the remaining space after excluding the bottom navigation. If you use `match_parent`, the bottom part of the fragment hides behind the bottom navigation bar

Comment: Thank you so so much !!

Answer (score 1):

Make `android:layout_height="0dp"` in your fragment, your bottom navigation is overlapping on top of your fragment